# Getting emulated pmem to work and create a device

Tags: linux-kernel

As per [pmem.io](https://docs.pmem.io/persistent-memory/getting-started-guide/creating-development-environments/linux-environments/linux-memmap#how-to-choose-the-correct-memmap-option-for-your-system) and [intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/training/how-to-emulate-persistent-memory-on-an-intel-architecture-server.html) persistent memory emulation pages, you are supposedly able to mark some memory as persistent and some linux driver will expose it as /dev/pmem#.  Unfortunately, while I am getting the memory marked as persistent and appear to have all of the correct drivers loaded, I am not getting /dev/pmem.

My kernel command line includes `nokaslr memmap=0x800000!0x1cc74058 iomem=relaxed` and the kernel boot says:

```
user: [mem 0x000000001cc74058-0x000000001d474057] persistent (type 12)
```

However, no /dev/pmem0 appeared.

Answer (score 2):

The persistent memory range needs to be aligned to the mapping size.  I picked that rather unusual address to start at, since it was the first address where a sufficiently sized chunk of ram started off from, to avoid fragmentation. However, experimentally the region must have a starting address *and* a size that is **better** than page aligned.  I am a bit confused by this since the source seems to indicate only page-alignment, but I ended up having to align 16MB for where I ended up.

The key was after sufficient loading and unloading of random modules, I found a complaint (which did not pop up by default):

```
nd_pmem namespace0.0: [mem 0x1cc74058-0x1d474057 flags 0x200] misaligned, unable to map
```

This also answers the question of: which driver is actually providing /dev/pmem# (nd_pmem).  Note that it does not exactly advertise that it attached in dmesg.  However, you can use `ndctl` to see what is going on, kinda.

```
> ndctl list
[
  {
    "dev":"namespace0.0",
    "mode":"fsdax",
    "map":"mem",
    "size":8388608,
    "sector_size":512,
    "blockdev":"pmem0"
  }
]
```

You can also access random information from `/sys/devices/platform/e820_pmem/ndbus0/region0` including `size` (mapping size in bytes) and `namespace0.0/resource` (starting address)

This (successful) test was done on a physical Intel i3-8100 with 16GB RAM and a H370 Pro4 motherboard.

Comment: Were you using VM? Could you share your CPU/system info. I'm having some trouble emulating PMEM with AMD processors. It just can't show persistent memory after setting memmap and reboot.

Comment: @hddmss: It was a physical Intel.  I'd suggest looking to see if the memory is marked as persistent during early kernel boot (the line I quoted appeared soon after "user-defined physical RAM map") and otherwise search dmesg for persistent and pmem.  Also, the character "!" in the memmap is important, and the order is size!starting which is a bit unusual.